# Azure Service Fabric application - hostname and host IP address

Tags: azure, azure-service-fabric, azure-vm-scale-set

From Azure service fabric application how to get the hostname and host IP address of the node which is serving the current request? please suggest.

Comment: Please add some more details. What workload is running. Are we talking .net apps using the service fabric SDK (stateful/stateless services or actor model)?

Comment: We are deploying .net stateless services as workload on Azure SF cluster.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Other then using environment variables you can use the [StatelessServiceContext](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.fabric.statelessservicecontext?f1url=%3FappId%3DDev16IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(System.Fabric.StatelessServiceContext);k(DevLang-csharp)%26rd%3Dtrue&view=azure-dotnet) class. It has a `NodeContext` property containing several interesting [properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.fabric.nodecontext?view=azure-dotnet). In your service you can get the fqdn/ip address like this:

```
var address = Context.NodeContext.IPAddressOrFQDN;
```

Afaik the Node Name isn't tied to a machine name, it is a logical name. Node name can be user defined name. I'd say `Environment.MachineName` or `Context.NodeContext.IPAddressOrFQDN` is the most accurate.

Comment: @ Peter Bons, what is the puprose of having logical name? Why do we need to have logical name though we have MachineName ? Is it because one machine/VM can have multiple nodes ie multiple instances of Fabric.exe and FabricGateway.exe?

Comment: I am not sure as I have never used it. I think the default is the name of the node type with the instance number as a prefix.

Answer (score 1):

These [environment variables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-environment-variables-reference) are made available by SF:

- `Fabric_NodeIPOrFQDN` - The IP or FQDN of the node, as specified in the cluster manifest file.    (e.g. localhost or 10.0.0.1)
- `Fabric_NodeName` -   The node name of the node running the process   (e.g. _Node_0)

Assuming that you're using C#, you can get an environment variable by [using](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.environment.getenvironmentvariable?view=net-5.0) `Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable`

Comment: @ LoekD Based on your above reply, I assume on context of Service Fabric its 'nodename' has to be treated as 'hostname' isn't it?

Comment: yes, hostname (internal) / machinename / nodename, but not the external domain name that's connected to the public IP of the Azure load balancer.